# Printing formatted string in C

Tags: c, formatting, printf

So I have a string of length 10. And I want to print the letters from 4-6[including both], and I want to span the output over a particular length L, with the digits being placed on the right side.

For eg

If I had the original String `123456789`, then the following code should display in the subsequent manner.

```
printf(Original);
printf(from 4-6, over 5 spaces)
```

Output:

```
123456789
  456
```

That is 456 is spread over 5 spaces and indented right.

How do I do it in C?

EDIT 1 : What if my width is not constant, and I have a variable, that dictates, the width. Similarly for the length of the substring is a variable. Any way of doing it now?

Can I do something like

```
printf("%%d.%ds",width,precision,expression);
```

Comment: divide the integer into particular array then print what ever array index you like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very direct:

```
printf("%5.3s\n", Original + 4);
         ^ ^
         | |
         | +--- precision, causes only 3 characters to be printed
         |
         +----- field width, sets total width of printed item
```

Since right-adjusting is the default, you get the desired output.

The precision "saves" us from having to extract the three characters into a properly terminated string of their own, very handy.

You can use dynamic values for either precision or field width (or both, of course) by specifying the width as `*` and passing an `int` argument:

```
const int width = 5, precision = 3;
printf("%*.*s\n", width, precision, Original + 4);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, say for example my field width is not constant, any way I can incorporate that? That is if I have `width` variable, that tells me the overall width.

Comment: Thanks, I thought of `printf("%\%d.\%ds",expression);`  That wont work here now, would it?

Comment: Wasn't just about the same question asked few moments ago although in a different manner ?

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *original = "123456789";

    printf("%5.3s\n", original + 3);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

if you want a precision based on a variable:

```
int prec = 2;

printf("%5.*s\n", prec, original + 3);
```

... same for width

Comment: I guess original plus 3 will start the string from 4, what makes it stop at 6?

Comment: 3 in %5.3s is the precision (max chars to be printed)

Comment: @DavidRF Edit to the question, if you could add to the answer?